# Where $Y$ is $-n$th root of product of $n$ Unif(0,1) variables, show $\sqrt n (Y-e)$ converges to normal

Tags: probability-theory, central-limit-theorem

I am given that $X_i$ are iid Unif(0,1), $i=1,\cdots,n$. $Y_n$ is defined as $Y_n=\left(\prod_{i=1}^n X_i\right)^{-1/n}$. I am to show that $\sqrt n (Y_n-e)$ converges in distribution to an $N(0,e^2)$ random variable as $n\to\infty$.

So far, I've mostly been trying to use log to transform this into something that looks like the central limit theorem will apply. However, I don't seem to make any headway that way. I can show, e.g., that
$$\mathbb P(\sqrt n (Y_n-e)<x) = \mathbb P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i > \log\left( \left(\frac x {\sqrt n} + e\right)^{-n} \right )\right)$$
But I can't see what to do with this. Am I on the right track? If so, how should I proceed?

Comment: Use the fact that $$[\sqrt n (Y_n-e)<x] = \left[\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i < x_n \right]$$ where $$Z_i=-\log X_i-1$$ is i.i.d. centered and $$x_n=\sqrt n\log \left(1+\frac x {e\sqrt n}\right)$$ hence $$\lim x_n=\frac{x}e$$

Comment: @Did As you suggested, I showed these things to be true. However, it's not clear to me how to use this. Is the resulting expression amenable to the CLT? If so, how?

Comment: What do you think could be the limit in distribution of $$\frac1{\sqrt n}\sum_{i=1}^nZ_i\ ?$$

Comment: Of course -- by the end of the day yesterday I was too brain-fogged to see that this can easily be put in the form of $\sqrt n$ times a sample mean minus the population mean. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CLT to show that $\sqrt{n} \left( Z_n -1 \right)  \xrightarrow{d} N(0,1)$, where
$$
Z_n =  \log (Y_n) =  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n - \log(X_i)
$$
then, use delta-method (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) with $g : x \mapsto e^x$ to show that $\sqrt{n}(Y_n - e) \xrightarrow{d} N(0,e^2)$.